# Como enviar una imagen en FastAPI a partir de un formulario HTML

Tags: html, python, flask, fastapi

Estoy tratando de cargar un formulario HTML en FastAPI, pero no he podido hacer que el código funcione, cuando envio el formulario obtengo este error:
**{"detail":[{"loc":["body","image"],"msg":"Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>","type":"value_error"}]}**. Creo que el formulario HTML no se esta enviando como deberia la imagen o no es el formato esperado.

Codigo HTML (utilizando Bootstrap):

```
    <h1 class="col">FastAPI Form</h1>
  </div>

  <form method="post" action="/data-processing"  class="row g-3 mx-sm-5 mx-2">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="validationDefaultUsername" class="form-label">Username</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">@</span>
        <input
          name="username"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="validationDefaultUsername"
          aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2"
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="validationDefault02" class="form-label">Age</label>
      <input name="age" type="number" class="form-control" id="validationDefault02" required />
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="validationDefault04" class="form-label">Country</label>
      <select name="country" class="form-select" id="validationDefault04" required>
        <option selected disabled value="">Choose...</option>
        <option value="ar">Argentina</option>
        <option value="can">Canada</option>
        <option value="co">Colombia</option>
        <option value="usa">UU.EE</option>
        <option value="ve">Venezuela</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="validationDefault05" class="form-label">Password</label>
      <input
        name="password_user"
        type="password"
        class="form-control"
        id="validationDefault05"
        required
      />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
      <label for="validationDefault06" class="form-label" >Image</label>
      <input
        name="image"
        type="file"
        class="form-control" 
        id="inputGroupFile01"
      />
    </div>


    <div class="col-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Esta es la funcion en Python utilizando FastAPI, no se si image: UploadFile = File(...) sea la forma obtener la imagen del formulario.

```
@app.post('/data-processing', tags=['user'])
def data_processing(username: str = Form(), age: int = Form(), country: str = Form(), password_user: str = Form(), image: UploadFile = File(...) ):
    user = {
        'username': username,
        'age': age,
        'country': country,
        'password': generate_hash(password_user),
        'image': image

    }
    db = Session()
    new_user = user_model(**user)
    db.add(new_user)
    db.commit()
    
    return RedirectResponse('/')
```

Comment: Diría que el problema puede deberse a que a tu `<form>` le falta `enctype="multipart/form-data"`